# Are there any limits for sending money from UK to Egypt

Tags: taxes, income-tax, united-kingdom, international-transfer, egypt

How much money can I send abroad each year to Egypt without being taxed? 
(Note: the money to be sent has already been taxed by income tax.)

For example, when searching online I found for [NRI -> India](https://www.compareremit.com/money-transfer-guide/sending-money-to-buy-overseas-property/)

> If you are an NRI, and wish to send money to India for purchasing property, you can send up to US$14,000 per person per year tax-free. For any amount that exceeds this limit, U.S. taxes will apply. Apart from this, there is no limit on the amount of money that can be sent abroad from the U.S. If you have paid the tax on the money you are sending, you do not need to pay tax again in India (according to Double Taxation Treaty between U.S & India). The recipient will be liable for paying taxes on the money received as income.

I'm looking for a similar statement but with respect for sending money from the UK to Egypt.
All I found is:

> The Double Taxation Convention entered into force on 23 August 1980.
>
> The convention become effective in Egypt from 1 January 1977 and in the UK from:
>
> 1 April 1977 for Corporation Tax
>   6 April 1977 for Income Tax and Capital Gains Tax

[1977 Egypt-UK Double Taxation Convention - in force](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/egypt-tax-treaties)

Answer (score 1):

The UK doesn't have any gift taxes for sending money in the same way as the US. I can't find any explicit references about receiving money in Egypt, but in general countries are perfectly happy for money to be sent in (if you're not money laundering or something) so it's unlikely there would be any restrictions on that side.

In relatively limited circumstances, it's possible that UK inheritance tax would end up applying. That's only possible at all if you were to die within 7 years of sending the money and your assets at death plus a proportion of the money sent in the 7 years before your death added up to more than £325,000.

There's some more information on how this would be worked out [here](https://www.gov.uk/inheritance-tax/gifts).

In the unlikely event that inheritance tax is a significant risk, you should try to make sure that the money sent falls under this category, in which case it would be exempted completely:

> normal gifts out of your income, for example Christmas or birthday
>   presents - you must be able to maintain your standard of living after
>   making the gift

There's some more detail about this exemption [here](https://www.gov.uk/hmrc-internal-manuals/inheritance-tax-manual/ihtm14231). For example if you were regularly sending money from your salary home to support a relative, it would probably come under this exemption.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you’ve found the statement you’re looking for. I didn’t read the whole 39 page pdf document but it does appear from your link that it is an in force treaty.

Comment: But it doesn't cover the law of what happens in Egypt for the recipient.

Comment: @Mark No, you’re right. It’s likely taxable, but it’s hard to say. The OP was aware of that possibility from the first example in the question.

Comment: I am the OP :))

Comment: Hah, sorry the phone makes it hard sometimes. You may want to ask about how Egypt handles or taxes foreign remittances in a separate question or clarify your question above. Unfortunately I have no idea about the Egypt end. Your contacts in Egypt would probably be more likely to know than us.